# Dependency shading in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jackson, dependencies, shadowjar

I am using a third party dependency which shades some jackson files as shaded.jackson.core.* or shaded.jackson.databind.* and uses it (as imports) in its application. However, I want to use a different version of jackson than the one shaded in this dependency. So, I was trying to use the relocate functionality in gradle to also shade the jackson dependencies similarly (with latest version) to the shaded.jackson and then use it.

```
  shadowJar {
      mergeServiceFiles()
      classifier = ''
      dependencies {
        include(dependency('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.6'))
        include(dependency('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.6'))
        include(dependency('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.6'))
      }
      relocate 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', 'shaded.jackson.core'
  }
```

But when I build the project with gradle then i get "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:shaded.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException". Here, the "shaded.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException" is called from some java class in the third-party dependency. Any suggestions or corrections are welcome!

Comment: Do you mean that you want the third party dependency to use a different version of Jackson, or that you want to use a different version of Jackson for the code that you write?

Comment: the third party to use a different version of jackson

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of shading is so that library developers can include particular versions of their dependencies without affecting the ability of users of their library to use different versions of such dependencies. So I don't know why you're trying to overwrite the shaded Jackson classes with a different version. You're bound to have problems, as the third party library that you're using hasn't been written to use Jackson version 2.9.6.

If you want to use Jackson 2.9.6 in the code that you write, then don't `relocate` the classes, and import `com.fasterxml.jackson.core...` into the classes that you write.